# How can i get default woocommerce product sorting options?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get list of default product sorting options in woocommerce like,sort by popularity,sort by average rating,sort by price etc.

Answer (score 2):

As of ver 3.5.4, WooCommerce default sorting option are as under:

- `id`
- `menu_order`
- `title`
- `relevance`
- `rand`
- `date`
- `price`
- `popularity`
- `rating`

You can find this in `get_catalog_ordering_args` function in `/includes/class-wc-query.php` file.

[Source](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/3.5.4/includes/class-wc-query.php#L434)

Comment: Thanks @kashif but It just gives the current selected sorted value. i just want all the list of default values used in product sorting mentioned above id, menu_order, title, relevence etc.

Comment: Did you check the ’get_catalog_ordering_args’ function?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any page builder plugin like WPbakery Page Builder? It has this function to sort by popularity, sort by average rating, sort by price etc.

Comment: Hi
i am not using any other plugin, i am developing my own plugin where i just need to get the list of default product sorting options.